# Is there a neater way to map member functions in dart?

Tags: dart, functional-programming

Dart has a handy map function on iterables, and it accepts a lambda. So I can write something like:

```
// Stupid example class
class Foo {
  int v;
  int v2() { return v*v; }
}

List<int> mapFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
  return foos.map( (Foo f) => f.v2() );
}
```

But this feels a little clunky to me. I'm used to being able to tell map to use the member function directly, something that would look more like:

```
// does not compile
List<int> mapFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
  return foos.map(Foo.v2);
}
```

But this fails to compile with the error:

```
The argument type '() → int' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(Foo) → int'
```

Is there some way to turn the member function into a lambda in a succinct way, so that
we can have something closer to the second example.

I could write

```
int applyV2(Foo f)  {
  return f.v2();
}

List<int> mapFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
  return foos.map(applyV2);
}
```

but then I'd need to create that for each member function I want to map, which isn't really any better than using the lambda function.

If it makes any difference I'm using dart 1 due to "legacy reasons", if this has changed in recent versions I'd love to know that too.

Comment: If it has the right signature you can do it.  v2 would have to accept a Foo as an argument.

Comment: @mmcdon20 indeed that is part of the problem, the version that fails to compile gives the error `The argument type '() → int' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(Foo) → int'.`

Comment: There isn't really something like you are describing where you give a method name and it gives you the exact lambda you are looking for. You could implement something along these lines using `dart:mirrors`, but mirrors only works on the dart vm, it wont work if you compile to javascript or machine code, and also I'm not sure if it was supported in dart 1 or to what extent.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no shorter way to create a function which takes a `Foo` and calls its `v2` method, than `(f) => f.v2()`.
You can omit the `Foo` type on the parameter, because it can be inferred from the context (a `List<X>.map<R>` requires an `R Function(X)` as argument).

You cannot tear off `Foo.v2` because `v2` is an interface method, not a static method.

Just to elaborate on why Dart doesn't allow that, you can stop reading now if you just want to know what works:
Some languages allow you to tear off instance methods, so `Foo.v2` becomes a function which expects its `this` object as an argument, in Dart a function of type `int Function(Foo)`. Dart does not allow that. Probably for many different reasons, but most importantly because it cannot work. Dart types are interfaces, all class types can be *implemented* by another class without inheriting any implementation.
If you then tear off `Foo.v2`, you can call it with an instance of another class which implements `Foo`, but which won't necessarily find the private fields that `Foo` has, and which `v2` could depend on.

Also, the tear-off would be covariant in its `this`-parameter.
Take `SubFoo` which extends `Foo` and has its own `v2` method. If you do `Foo foo = SubFoo(); var vtoo = foo.v2;` then the static type of `vtoo` will be `int Function(Foo)`, but the implementation from `SubFoo` will necessarily have runtime type `int Function(SubFoo)`, which is *not a subtype of* the static type. That means it's unsound. The torn off function will have to do a run-time type check that its argument is actually a `SubFoo`, and throw if it's not. (So, that feature is not a good match for Dart.)